# Why do three-scalar correlation functions vanish by parity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, parity

We have the following Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal L = \frac12 (\partial_\mu \phi)^2 - \frac12 m^2 \psi^2 + \bar\psi(\mathrm i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -M) \psi - \mathrm i g \bar\psi \gamma^5 \psi \phi \,.
$$

It is invariant under parity which is given to act like so:
$$
\psi(t, \vec x) \to \gamma^0 \psi(t, - \vec x)
\,\qquad
\phi(t, \vec x) \to - \phi(t, - \vec x) \,.
$$

In the further analysis of the renormalization of this theory we used that the following class of diagrams vanish due to parity:

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2016-01-28/blob-1.png

The argument that we could come up with is the following: We can just insert pairs of the parity operator in the three-point-function like so:
$$
\langle \Omega | \phi(x) \phi(y) \phi(z) | \Omega \rangle
= \langle \Omega | P \phi(x) PP \phi(y) PP \phi(z) P | \Omega \rangle
= (-1)^3 \langle \Omega | \phi(-x) \phi(-y) \phi(-z) | \Omega \rangle
$$
The points $x$, $y$, $z$ always lie in a single plane. The Lagrangian is $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ symmetric and we can therefore rotate and translate that plane back to the original positions. The minus sign from the parity will remain and therefore this amplitude has to vanish.

This argument looks valid but it does not generalize to more than three legs. Since the tadpole diagram with one scalar leg also vanishes it seems like every diagram with an odd number of scalar legs would vanish.

Is there are more general argument for this?

Comment: You mean $\phi(t,\vec x)\mapsto-\phi(t,-\vec x)$ and not $\psi$ on the r.h.s., right? Also, do you *know* that all diagrams with odd scalar legs vanish or do you only suspect it?

Comment: Oh, I had a lot of $\psi$ where I actually meant $\phi$. Now it should be fixed. We were told that it vanishes but we the argument turned out to be not quite sound, so we are looking for another argument.